# I want to show my image in the console ? (using PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create a simple CS:GO case opening simulator game. I am new to programming and python but the thing is I can't open the image in my console, it pops up on the screen.

Is there a way to show images in my console ?

Here is my code which generates random item from random case.
I want to show this item's picture in the console or in the game

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("C:/Users/pc/Downloads/images.jpg")

image.show()
```

The code works but it shown in my photos not in console.

Comment: How do you want to show the image in the console? Console is a textual interface.

Comment: You cannot show an image on the console.